# Not able to pass data between activities.Data is blank

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass some data from one activity to another and I have made a toast in the other activity to see if data is being passed.When the toast shows up it is blank.I have done everything right and tried many different times with different methods I have also created another app but the problem still stays.It gives me null.

**My java code in the first activity**

```
public class titleandcuisine extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

public static final String TITLE_GET = "title";
    public static final String CUISINE_GET = "cuisine";

    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;
    Spinner spinner;
    EditText dish;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_titleandcuisine);


        dish = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.cuisines,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        button = findViewById(R.id.next);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.close);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), homepage.class));
            }
        });


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = dish.getText().toString();
                String text2 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Intent data = new Intent(getBaseContext(),imagepost.class);
               data.putExtra(TITLE_GET,text);
               data.putExtra(CUISINE_GET,text2);
                startActivity(data);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

**Second activity java code**

```
public class reviewactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView cuisine,title;
    ImageView displayimage,back;
    Uri myUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reviewactivity);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String titleget = intent.getStringExtra(titleandcuisine.TITLE_GET);
        String cuisineget = intent.getStringExtra(titleandcuisine.CUISINE_GET);


        Toast.makeText(this, titleget + cuisineget, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        cuisine = findViewById(R.id.reviewcuisine);
        title = findViewById(R.id.reviewtitle);
        back = findViewById(R.id.backtopostvideo);
        displayimage = findViewById(R.id.reviewdisplaimage);

       // cuisine.setText(cuisineget);
       // title.setText(titleget);

       // myUri = Uri.parse(uri);
        displayimage.setImageURI(myUri);


        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),videopost.class));
            }
        });

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the text from the `EditText` when the button is clicked. Something like:

```
 title = dish.getText().toString(); // Add this
 Intent data = new Intent(getBaseContext(),imagepost.class);
 data.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title);
 ...
```

One more thing: You are trying to read the `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` at the `reviewactivity` activity. However, nothing is starting that activity (at least within the piece of code that you shared).

Comment: I please check I have edited and tried a different method,also did what you said.But it is still giving me null.